# Mouse-Events are not getting fired when Mouse Button is pressed

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

when a mouse button is pressed on a control, it doesn't fire any events on it anymore.
I need that, since i wanted to enable myself to navigate through a control by "dragging" it.

The Drag events aren't getting fired either. Don't know why it is this way. It's useless.
I need an event thats getting fired when the mouse moves. Where is it?

**Edit:** 
Look, when you hold the left mouse-button on Google-Map, you can move on the map with your mouse movement. I want to do the same thing with my UserControl. I overrided the OnPaint-Method so it would simply displays a grid. I have also implemented functions to move around with keys. It all works so far. Now i want to move around with the mouse by holding down the left mouse-button and move it. It should be easy and obvious, but it isn't.

So i subscribed all the mouse- and drag-events. Like that:

```
public partial class GameBoard : UserControl
{
    private int m_CellWidth = 5;
    private int m_CellHeight = 5;
    private Point m_Position = Point.Empty;
    private Point m_MousePoint = Point.Empty;

    public GameBoard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ResizeRedraw = true;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Point firstPoint = new Point(m_Position.X % m_CellWidth, m_Position.Y % m_CellHeight);
        int countVisibleCols = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)((double)Width / (double)m_CellWidth));
        int countVisibleRows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)((double)Height / (double)m_CellHeight));

        Pen artistsPen = new Pen(Brushes.Black);

        for (int i = 0; i < countVisibleCols; i++)
        {
            Point startPoint = new Point(firstPoint.X + i * m_CellWidth, 0);
            Point endPoint = new Point(firstPoint.X + i * m_CellWidth, Height);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(artistsPen, startPoint, endPoint);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < countVisibleRows; i++)
        {
            Point startPoint = new Point(0, firstPoint.Y + i * m_CellHeight);
            Point endPoint = new Point(Width, firstPoint.Y + i * m_CellHeight);
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(artistsPen, startPoint, endPoint);
        }
    }

    private void GameBoard_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void GameBoard_DragLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

(Actual subscriptions happens in the designer.)
The Problem is: If the left mouse-button has beeing clicked & hold on my control, NOT ONE of those events are getting fired anymore. So i don't know how to implement the desired feature.

Comment: can you provide more code to help us see your problem ?

Comment: At this point you haven't provided any information to be able to debug the issue.  I'm not sure how anyone can answer your question without some more details.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `MouseMove()` event.  You can determine if the Left button is down during a move using the `e.Button` parameter.  Here's an example with a Button:

```
    private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            this.Text = "Left: " + e.X.ToString() + ", " + e.Y.ToString();
        }
        else if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.None)
        {
            this.Text = e.X.ToString() + ", " + e.Y.ToString();
        }   
    }
```

Not all controls behave the same, however.  Give more details about exactly which control you're trying to use and how.

Answer (score 0):

In the Visual Studio designer for a form, there's an Events button in the Properties window of a component that typically looks like a lightning bolt.  You can use this to tie events to functions.  Could this be missing?